# Query for random row selection

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, random

i want to make database FLAT Allotment to applicants who registered using sql 2008 as back end and vb.net 2010 as front end. 40% applicant allotted flat in first draw randomly

```
CUSTID  CUSTNAME    ACCTNO  BAL              AGE    ADDRESS
1        SHYAM      501     Rs. 2,50,000.00  34     SAKET NEW
2        RAM        502     Rs. 3,27,000.00  21     SEC 3 PUSHP VIHAR
3        MOHAN      503     Rs. 1,50,000.00  25     M B ROAD MEHROLI
4        JOHAN      504     Rs. 5,10,000.00  34     M G ROAD GURGAON
```

how to select random row from above data table in ms access

Comment: Please do not edit original questions with other which have nothing to do with. You can ask a new question instead. I've reverted the changes to restore the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Select a random row with Microsoft SQL Server:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM YourTableName
 ORDER BY NEWID()
```

MS Access

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM YourTableName ORDER BY RND(CUSTID)
```